# How to implement birthday for all browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, safari

Hello I'm trying to implement a birthday selection input for a site I'm building and I need some advice- should I include the  element inside of an  element or nah? I want the option to post the users bday to the server as a date without using the date type of the  element as it isn't supported in Safari or ie9 or older. Also, is it possible to display a different day selection option depending on the month chosen, like 29 days for Feb and 31 for months with 31 days (30 for months with 30) with like JavaScript or something? Thanks, below is my code.

```
<label>Birthday:</label><select name="year">
<option value="2019" selected>2019</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
...Etc years...
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: they are many datePicker ...

Comment: I see, I will have to do some research. Is there one you would recommend based on it's features or reputation or cross-platform build? Thanks for your time...

Comment: not really, look at :  https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=datePicker&type=Repositories.   Ifound this one with google (for no dependencies => https://github.com/qodesmith/datepicker